# typing react hook form props react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

i have multiple  different forms  in separate components using react hook form and yup resolver
,  i've searched for hours ,but I could not decide precisely how to type or how it should be.
can anyone help me to type the following props or if there is any way to restructuring my forms to get easy to handle .but really I need to be best practice
it would be appreciated

CreateCar.tsx

```
export type RegisterSpecsSchemaProps = Car|Omit<Car,id_car_card>;


const CreateCar = ({mode,id

}:CreateCarProps) => {


  const registerSpecsSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    carName: Yup.string().required('car Name is required'),
    carModel: Yup.string().required('car Model is required')
    
     carYear: Yup.string().required('car year is required')
     .number().required('car year  is required'),
     carClass: Yup.string().required('car Class is required')
     
   
    },
    []);

const {   
     handleSubmit:handleSubmitCarSpecs,
    formState: { errors:carSpecsErrors },
     control:controlSpecs 
     //,setValue
     ,getValues:getSpecsValues
     ,reset:resetSpecs
    } = useForm<RegisterSpecsSchemaProps>({
            resolver: yupResolver(registerSpecsSchema)  ,
            mode:'onBlur',
      });

const {  
     handleSubmit:handleSubmitCarFeatures,
    formState: { errors:carFeaturesErrors }
    , control:controlFeatures 
    //,setValue
    ,getValues:getFeaturesValues
    ,reset:resetFeatures
    } = useForm<any>({
          //  resolver: yupResolver(registerFeaturesSchema)  ,
            mode:'onBlur',
          });

  const {  
    handleSubmit:handleSubmitCarGallery,
    formState: {  errors:carGalleryErrors }
    , control:controlGallery
     //,setValue
     ,getValues:getGalleryValues
     ,reset:resetGallery
    } = useForm<any>({
          //  resolver: yupResolver(registerGallerySchema)  ,
            mode:'onBlur',
          });   
          

const onSubmitSpecs: SubmitHandler<any>=(data)=>{
           //...
              }

const onSubmitGallery: SubmitHandler<any>=(data)=>{
            //...
              }

const onSubmitFeatures: SubmitHandler<any>=(data)=>{
            //...
              }

return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
     
       <div className={styles.car_specs_features}>

        <CarSpecsForm  control={controlSpecs} onSubmit={onSubmitSpecs}
        errors={carSpecsErrors} handleSubmitCarSpecs={handleSubmitCarSpecs}   />

        <CarFeaturesForm   />                 //same props here

       </div>

       <div className={styles.car_gallery}>
        <CarGalleryForm    />                   //same props here
       </div>

       <div className={styles.submit_form}>
       {
     <Button  sort={'primary'}
      value={mode==='create'?'create':'update'} type="submit"
     form={'dealerForm'} />
    }
       </div>
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateCar
```

CarSpecsForm.tsx

```
type CarSpecsFormProps =   // I want to type correctly here
{
    handleSubmitCarSpecs: ??
    onSubmit:  ?
    errors:?
    control: ?
    reset:?

}  ; 


const CarSpecsForm = () => {


   const [submitButtonText, setSubmitButtonText] = useState<string>('submit')
    const [carImage, setCarImage] = useState<object>()
    const [previewCarImg, setPreviewCarImg] = useState<string>('');

    const handleImageUpload = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
        ) =>{
          e.preventDefault();
          const selectedFiles = e.target.files as FileList
           setCarImage(selectedFiles?.[0])
           setPreviewCarImg(URL.createObjectURL(selectedFiles?.[0]));

    }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmitCarSpecs()}>
       <div className={styles.upload_profile_container}>
    { 
      mode ===  ('create') ? 
     <LocalImage  src={previewCarImg?previewCarImg:Profile} />
     //:<Image src={ dealer!.carImg} />
    :
    carSpecs && mode ===  ('edit') ? 
    previewCarImg?
    <LocalImage sort={'profile'}  src={previewCarImg} />
    : carSpecs!.carImg
    && carSpecs!.carImg !== undefined ?
     <Image src={ carSpecs!.src} />
    :<LocalImage  src={Profile} />
    
    //create mode
    :
    carSpecs && mode !== 'preview' && !carSpecs.carImg
    && carSpecs.carImg === undefined  ? 
    carSpecs && <Image src={ carSpecs!.carImg} />
    :
   <LocalImage   src={Profile} />
     } 
      
        <Controller 
         control={control}
         name={'carImage'}
         render={({ field }) =>
         <UploadFile
         {...field}
        className={styles.upload_input}
         multiple={false}
         name={"carImage"}
         disabled={mode === 'preview' ?true :false}
         onChange={e=>{
          handleImageUpload(e);
          field.onChange(e.target.files![0]); 
        }} /> 
      }
         /> 
      </div>

    <Button  sort={'primary'}
      value={'add specs'} type="submit"
     form={'car_specs'} />
    </form>
  )
//...other fields
}

export default CarSpecsForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `CreateCar` component, it seems that `CarSpecsForm` should receive the following props:

List item

- `handleSubmitCarSpecs`: A function which is used to handle form submission.
- `onSubmit`: A function which is used to process the form's data after it is submitted.
- `errors`: An object which contains form validation error messages.
- `control`: An object from react-hook-form to control the form.
- `reset`: A function to reset the form fields.

We can create types for these props in TypeScript :-

```
import { Control, FieldErrors, SubmitHandler, UseFormReset } from "react-hook-form";

export type RegisterSpecsSchemaProps = Omit<Car, "id_car_card">;

type CarSpecsFormProps = {
  handleSubmitCarSpecs: (event?: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => Promise<void>;
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<RegisterSpecsSchemaProps>;
  errors: FieldErrors<RegisterSpecsSchemaProps>;
  control: Control<RegisterSpecsSchemaProps>;
  reset: UseFormReset<RegisterSpecsSchemaProps>;
};
```

This will correctly type the props for the `CarSpecsForm` component.

You should replace the `CarSpecsForm` function component's parameters with the `CarSpecsFormProps` like so:

```
const CarSpecsForm: React.FC<CarSpecsFormProps> = ({
  handleSubmitCarSpecs,
  onSubmit,
  errors,
  control,
  reset,
}) => {
  // ... rest of your component
};
```

You will need to do the same for CarFeaturesForm and CarGalleryForm, creating an appropriate typescript type for the props, and applying them to each component respectively.

Regarding restructuring your form for better handling, one suggestion would be to combine the three separate forms (`CarSpecsForm`, `CarFeaturesForm`, and `CarGalleryForm`) into one form. This would let you handle submission and validation in one place. However, if these forms have different business requirements (e.g., they are displayed in different places or times, or have different behaviors), it might be best to keep them separate.

Make sure you properly defined and imported the Car type, it should be a type that accurately represents a car object in your application.